# JQuery FadeOut function not occurring on the first attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which has an unordered list down one side, to switch between different containers with images inside to the right of the list.

The page in question is at the following URL with the JQuery code in the head tag:

http://dev.bathroomwarehouse.com/bathrooms.html

After clicking an item on the left as soon as the page has loaded (for example 'Burgundy') the images to the right (encapsulated by a div container) disappears without animation, despite the 'fadeOut' function in JQuery being used.

After the first change, the fadeOut function acts as expected, and the div to the right fades out, and the new div fades in.

Can anyone help figure out why this is happening?

The code in question is below:

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".catList li").click(function() {

            $(".catList li").removeClass('selectedRange');
            $(this).addClass("selectedRange");
            var clickedItem = $(this).index(".catList li");

            $(".images div").stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(".images div").removeClass("selectedImageGroup");
            });

            $(".images div:eq(" + clickedItem + ")").delay(750).fadeIn(function () {
                $(".images div:eq(" + clickedItem + ")").addClass("selectedImageGroup");
            });


        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imageSelector">
        <ul class="catList">
            <li class="selectedRange"><h2>Ivory</h2>Modernist suite featuring with a touch of nostalgia…</li>
            <li><h2>Burgundy</h2>Contemporary classic...</li>
            <li><h2>Evergreen</h2>Minimalist with a unique shower feature...</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="vertLine">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="images">
            <div class="imageGroup selectedImageGroup">
                <table class="imageGroupTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="imageGroupMainImage">
                            <img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Main.jpg" alt="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="imageGroupSmallImages">
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Img1.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Img2.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Img3.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="imageGroup">
                <table class="imageGroupTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="imageGroupMainImage">
                            <img src="img/ImageBrowser/B2/Main.jpg" alt="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="imageGroupSmallImages">
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B2/Img1.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B2/Img2.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B2/Img3.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="imageGroup">
                <table class="imageGroupTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="imageGroupMainImage">
                            <img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Main.jpg" alt="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="imageGroupSmallImages">
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Img1.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Img2.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><img src="img/ImageBrowser/B1/Img3.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question. A live link is fine, but it might disappear tomorrow and the community would prefer your question to survive that event.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FhCBY/

Comment: Thanks, can you tell why it doesn't work on my live page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `display: block!important;` overriding `display: none;` on your container div. (I can't explain why it doesn't work, but that is the cause of the issue.) It works after clicking once because it sets the inline style to `display:block;`. If you remove the CSS line of `display:none` for the element, the fade works on the first as well.

Example breakage: [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/FhCBY/1/), [working](http://jsfiddle.net/FhCBY/)

Comment: Thanks, I can see why this is now and I have changed appropriately. I removed the important override, and made the div appear programatically rather than using the CSS.

Comment: @Lukes123 well, it doesn't make too much sense that it doesn't work from CSS but it works from the inline style. Taking a look into jQuery to see if I can find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
$('.images div:first').show();
```

right after

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```